# How to add capcha for node/edit form

Tags: 7, nodes, captcha

I need to add captcha for node edit form, not for the front-end form. please can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are  using [Captcha](https://drupal.org/project/captcha) module..

- Go to admin/config/people/captcha
- Enable "Add CAPTCHA administration links to forms" and "Allow CAPTCHAs and CAPTCHA administration links on administrative pages"

[image]

- Go to node edit page you see setting like below

[image]

- Enable captcha for form

Comment: Great :-) Welcome to SO. If one of the answers above fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/187716